# What is special about $x^T P y$?

Tags: matrices, bilinear-form

We know that if a matrix $P$ is positive definite, then for any vector $x \ne 0$, $x^T P x > 0$. But what about $x^T P y$ where $x \ne y$?

Comment: Well it's not the case that $x^TPy>0$ as you can check in just one dimension where $x=1$, $P=1$, and $y=-1$. However, we can use $P$ to form an inner product, so that's cool.

Comment: What do you mean by forming an inner product?

Comment: Check this out https://math.berkeley.edu/~peyam/Math110Sp13/Handouts/Dot%20products.pdf

Comment: @winston Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1):

$$\rm x^{\top} P \, y = \frac 12 \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ \mathrm y\end{bmatrix}^{\top} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm O & \mathrm P\\ \,\mathrm P^{\top} & \,\mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ \mathrm y\end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial of the block matrix above is

$$\det \begin{bmatrix} s \mathrm I & -\mathrm P\\ -\mathrm P^{\top} & s\mathrm I\end{bmatrix} = \det( s^2 \mathrm I - \mathrm P \mathrm P^{\top} )$$

where $\mathrm P \mathrm P^{\top}$ is positive semidefinite. The spectrum of the block matrix contains the positive and negative square roots of the (nonnegative) eigenvalues of $\mathrm P \mathrm P^{\top}$. Hence, the block matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm O & \mathrm P\\ \,\mathrm P^{\top} & \,\mathrm O\end{bmatrix}$$

is **indefinite**, and so is the bilinear form $\rm x^{\top} P \, y$.